# How to create serialize Scala Array?

Tags: php

I have one array and  i want to use this array for highcharts. I try to make changes in `for each` loop but not getting proper array.

**Query result**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MainsPower] => 255
            [timestamp] => 2015-10-07T14:28:41.545Z


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MainsPower] => 0
            [timestamp] => 2015-10-15T14:28:41.545Z
                )

        )
)
```

**And I want result like follows:**

```
[2015-10-7,0],
[2015-10-15,0]
```

**my `for each` loop:**

```
$output_array = array();
    foreach ($result as  $output) {
        $output_array[] = $output['MainsPower'] . ' , ' .$output['timestamp'];
    }
    pr($output_array);exit;
```

Please suggest me what needs to be changes in code to get it working as expected.

Comment: Show your `foreach` code!!

Comment: Are you actually talking about JSON? What does Scala have to do with this?

Comment: Post what you did, let me see this foreach

Comment: actually i am try but not shows bcoz very stupid foreach @Saty

Comment: is it possible to you create foreach @Saty

Comment: ....We're not here to do your work for you. Show your working, then maybe we can help.

Comment: Yes @JonStirling but i littile confuse how to ask question..

Comment: updated my question added my foreach loop @Saty

Comment: Improved english and formatted the question for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

you can format your wanted date by `date` function

```
foreach ($result as  $output) {
        $output_array[] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($output['timestamp'])). ' , ' .$output['MainsPower'];
    }
    var_dump($output_array);
```